# TAILWINDCSS: How do I stop the page from minimizing smaller than this breakpoint? See images for reference

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

The page can currently be minimized to a very skinny length as shown in the image below.

[image]

How can I set the smallest breakpoint screen the page can minimize to about this size?
[image]

The following is my code for the page. This is a component in a react project:

```
<section id="hero-section" class="bg-blue-100 text-white min-w-0">
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <div class="flex flex-col mx-auto max-w-sm xs:max-w-md sm:max-w-xl mt-20 sm:mt-30 text-center">
            <p class="sm:text-6xl font-semibold mb-6 xs:text-5xl text-4xl leading-none font-montserrat">
              A powerful tool to organize your day
            </p>
            <p class="text-gray-400 font-lora text-md xs:text-lg font-thin italic">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore
              facilis aut nobis amet vitae.
            </p>
            <div class="xs:space-x-3 space-y-3 xs:space-y-0 pt-8 flex flex-col mx-auto xs:flex-row font-light text-sm text-white">
              <button
                className="px-20 xs:px-5 py-2 bg-indigo-500 border border-indigo-500 rounded-sm hover:bg-indigo-600 hover:border-indigo-600"
                onClick={() => history("/register")}
              >
                Create an account
              </button>
              <button
                className="xs:px-5 py-2 bg-gray-600 border border-gray-500 rounded-sm hover:bg-gray-500 text-gray-300"
                onClick={() => history("/login")}
              >
                Sign in
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* <div class="">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BPT2rdW.png" />
        </div> */}
        <div class="pt-20 sm:pt-40">
          {/* Curve SVG */}
          <div class="curve">
            <svg
              data-name="Layer 1"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
              preserveAspectRatio="none"
            >
              <path
                d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z"
                class="shape-fill"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Tried using min-w to prevent the page from minimizing any more but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

xs isn't a breakpoint supplied by Tailwind. Is this one you have created yourself? By default, any property that doesn't have a size associated to it - i.e. `text-3xl` - will remain that size until it hits a viewport targeting the same properties. So if you have `text-3xl sm:text-4xl`, text-3xl is your default property on any viewport less than 640px (sm)

Comment: I added the XS breakpoint myself. I understand that I need an element's properties to target a specific viewport but is there a way to prevent the viewport from minimizing past a certain width?

Comment: Try setting a min-w with no xs